# Why is there no Script option to attach to when Remote Debugging from VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp-classic, remote-debugging

**Spot The Difference!**

[image: **Attach To Local Process**]

This is the list of code types I am allowed to "Attach to:" against local processes.

[image: **Attach To Remote Process**]

This is the list of code types I am allowed to "Attach to:" against remote processes.

Why am I unable to attach to Script remotely?

I am trying to do this to allow me to remotely debug Classic ASP in Visual Studio 2010.

I have enabled server side script debugging for the website containing my ASP pages and I've identified the w3wp.exe process that is loading asp.dll.

The remote web server is IIS6/Win Server 2003 running as a VirtualBox Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I eventually dug this MSDN blog post up,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2006/03/15/552108.aspx) in which it is stated:

> Sadly, there just isn't any way to do remote script debugging. If you
>   need remote script debugging, my only suggestion would be to use
>   Remote Desktop and run Visual Studio on your server.

The article explains that ASP support was cut in Visual Studio 2005 due to changes in the debugger implementation, OS changes and project priorities.

Sadly for me, I didn't gain the privilege of working with Classic ASP until 2013! (wiggly eyebrow smiley face)